# Django template timezone in :date filter - is abbreviation possible?

Tags: django, templates, timezone

If I write `{{some_time|date:"h:i A T"}}` in a django template, it outputs "12:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time". I would prefer the short timezone format "EDT". Any way you can do this?

Comment: I think you might have to roll your own - weirdly the docs suggest that the output will be what you want (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#now), but I get the same output as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like on my Windows Django dev environment, it returns "Eastern Daylight Time". However, on my Ubuntu 8.04 LTS installation, it returns "EDT" like the documentation shows. Perhaps it is returning the underlying OS's timezone string?

Now that the behavior is known, I can code around it.